# Use a generic string as the key of an object

Tags: typescript

I want to define an object `O` that is generic over some type argument `T extends string` in such a way that the object `O` always has a key with the value of `T`.

```
type O<T extends string> = { [t in T]: string };

function f<T extends string>(t: T, o: O<T>) {
    const x = o[t];
    return x === "hello";
}

let s = f("a", { a: "" })

if (s === "Hello") {

}
```

This is what I tried but it doesn't actually work since `O[T]` is not inferred to string. This means that the last `if` has an error because TypeScript the comparison will always be `false`.

[TypeScript Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20O%3CT%20extends%20string%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bt%20in%20T%5D%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0A%0Afunction%20f%3CT%20extends%20string%3E(t%3A%20T%2C%20o%3A%20O%3CT%3E)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20x%20%3D%20o%5Bt%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20x%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22hello%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20s%20%3D%20f(%22a%22%2C%20%7B%20a%3A%20%22%22%20%7D)%0A%0Aif%20(s%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22Hello%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%7D)

Comment: What doesn't work exactly?  There are no errors in that code, and you are able to annotate x if you want like `const x: string = o[t]` with no error.  Where's the problem?

Comment: My issue is having to annotate to get the right type.

Comment: You don't *have* to annotate it, but the fact that you *can* means that the compiler does understand that `O<T>[T]` is assignable to `string`.  If your issue is that inspecting the type of `x` in IntelliSense shows `O<T>[T]` instead of `string`, then your question should explain why that's an issue for you.  Is it just aesthetics?  Or does some code somewhere actually break because of the difference?   Right now I'm just seeing "it doesn't work" and "I don't like it", instead of a [mcve], so it's hard to know how to proceed here.  Good luck!

Comment: The problem is that not assigning to string does result in errors further down below. My apologies, I should have made that clear in the question itself. I edited the question to reflect that. Anyway, it seems clear to me that assigning to string is the only valid solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`O[T]` will not directly show up as `string` but it will behave as `string` for all intents and purposes:

```
type O<T extends string> = { [t in T]: string };

function f<T extends string>(t: T, o: O<T>) {
    let x = o[t];
    let s: string = x; // assignable to string 
    x = "S" // string can be assigned to it
    return x;
}
let s: string = f("a", {a: ""}) // outside it is string
```